# Вывод переменной при условии в Smarty - как оптимальней?

Tags: php, html, smarty

Есть меню навигации

```
<a href="/" class="nav-link active">
```

Необходимо вывести active при условии, если url = 123

```
<a href="/" class="nav-link {if $url == '123'} active {/if}">
```

Эта запись оптимальна?

Comment: Для оптимальности есть критерий. Какой критерий оптимальности у тебя?

Comment: Чтобы заказчик не уволил. Он придирчивый

Comment: Если заказчик увольняет за такое - он скудоумный.

Comment: меню у вас, надо полагать, в цикле каком-то выводится,так покажите целикомо вывод, а не одну строчку. Ибо если у вас 20 пунктов прописаны ручками, то это  не оптимально, хоть строка данная и будет выглядеть вполне прилично